# correct number of decimals

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

I'm reading Sauers textbook on Numerical Methods.

An exercise where I use the Bisection method to apporoximate a root to a given function, the answer is supposed to be given with six correct decimals.

My question. If the function I use gives me an error of max $5*10^{-8}$ and my approximate root is $r_a=1.12345448000$

Disregarding the computational error of the computer, the root should be within $r= \pm  5*10^{-8}$.

It could max be $1.12345453000$ and min $1.12345443000$. Rounded these would be $1.123455$ and $1.123454$. It is not hard to imagine a smaller error (e.g. $5*10^{-14}$ but with a approximate root of $1.123454499...996$ where max approx root would be $1.123454500...001$ and min $1.123454499...991$. How do I round to the sixth decimal in this case?

Comment: Yes, this is a not avoidable problem of translating interval radius and number of valid digits. By the usual convention it just means that the final interval should have length less than $10^{-6}$ or radius less than $5\cdot 10^{-7}$, if the decimals are the digits after the dot. You do not have to continue until the 6th decimal stabilizes (but check previous examples in your course).